# Medical text corpus

Tags: data-request, medical, machine-learning, nlp

This should be a simple question to many in the area, but for the life of me I can't find a solution by myself.

I need a corpus of medical text for the purposes of training a spell checker which will be used on... medical text. For this I need a large amount of text that has few (or ideally no) errors in it. The abstracts from Medline articles would be a good bet.

However, while I can many solutions that are grossly more complicated than I require (such as [treebank](http://www.geniaproject.org/genia-corpus/treebank)) designed for tree-building or POS tasks, and would require significant work to remove annotation and compile into a single .txt, surely such a resource already exists?

Alternatively I could just visit a hundred or so Medline articles and start copy-pasting their abstract details I suppose...

Comment: What do you want to spell check? medical research articles, or physician notes?

Comment: @FranckDernoncourt it would be physician notes: so terse, and domain specific term heavy. Lots of acronyms as well, but I'm handling those separately (for the purposes of spell-checking, simply ignoring them)